# tail recursion performance on template meta-programming

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, recursion, template-meta-programming

A common compiler optimization is to transform tail-recursive functions into loops, speeding up the execution time and reducing memory (stack) consumption:

```
int go_to_zero( int n )
{
    if( n == 0 )
        return 0;
    else
        return go_to_zero( n - 1 );
}
```

My question is simple: **Is there any performance benefit (i.e. reducing compile time) doing tail-recursive algorithms on template meta-programming?**

Here an example:

```
template<typename... Ts>
struct list {};


template<typename LIST>
struct reverse;


template<typename HEAD , typename... TAIL>
struct reverse<list<HEAD,TAIL...>>
{
    using result = concat<typename reverse<list<TAIL...>>::result,list<HEAD>>;
};

template<>
struct reverse<list<>>
{
    using result = list<>;
};
```

versus:

```
template<typename INPUT , typename OUTPUT>
struct reverse_impl;


template<typename HEAD , typename... TAIL , tyename... Ts>
struct reverse_impl<list<HEAD,TAIL...>,list<Ts...>>
{
    using result = typename reverse_impl<list<TAIL...>,list<Ts...,HEAD>>::result;
};

template<typename... Ts>
struct reverse_impl<list<>,list<Ts...>>
{
    using result = list<Ts...>;
};

template<typename LIST>
using reverse = typename reverse_impl<LIST,list<>>::result;
```

Comment: what do you mean by performance benefits ? tail recursion and template meta programming don't fall into the same category. Templates are evaluated at compiletime while the function is optimized for runtime.

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/12/dont-be-afraid-to-use-the-science/

Comment: @Raxvan the question is pretty clear: I'm asking for any performance benefit when writting metafunctions in a tail-recursion way instead of other forms of recursion. By performance benefits I mean compilation time reduction and (possibly?) compiler RAM usage reduction. Finally note that **tail-recursion and template metaprogramming are very related concepts, because tmp is just a form of functional programming inside C++**.

Comment: @Raxvan you should read a question properly before judging it! The structure of my question is: **1. (Human friendly) introduction to tail recursion, and its well known performance benefits. 2. tmp related question: Possible benefit of tail-recursion on tmp (Time and compiler resources)**

Comment: Nice question! I've always used the 1st version, because I never thought of the 2nd one! Just by looking at them, I bet the 2nd is more efficient, simply because it avoids `concat` so it should require roughly half template instantiations compared to the 1st. But because compiler implementations may be immensely different (e.g. I expect clang to be much faster than gcc on such tasks), I would say that, as always, theoretical discussions on performance without measurements are pointless. Complexity is linear in both cases but this doesn't say much.

Comment: What is that concat template, where is it defined?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In [C++ Template Metaprogramming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B003XNTTBW) Appendix C "Compile Time Performance" Abraham and Gurtovoy messured how memoization  of template instantiation effects compile time. The book was written in 2005 and I think memoization is better implemented today (I didn't measure). So the question to answer is which implementation can benefit more from memoization. I have edited the code a little bit [Version 1](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/40257a1bc5990466) and [Version 2](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7315df7cbc9aa820). Now it will emit an error when `reverse_impl` is instantiated, so we can simply count the errors. I reverse 2 lists `list<int, short, char>` and `list<short, char>`. Version 1 emits 4 errors and Version 2 emits 7 errors. In this particular case Version 1 benefits from memoization with these two lists (list2 is the tail of list1) and Version 2 doesn't. So I would expect Version 1 is faster.

So it would be best to implement algorithms in terms of other algorithms which are known to benefit from memoization and I think most of them use head recursion.

Answer (score 1):

All the pros and cons of regular vs. tail recursion apply also to the metaprogramming. The difference in this case is that instead of the execution of a compiled program on a target machine, the program is executed in a compiler sand-box and compiles to the target language instead of to the machine language. This process is conceptually not much different from compiling a Java program into a bytecode.

C++ compilers have rather limited allowed depth of template nesting (~hundreds) and if the algorithm grows exponentially, it can be a blocker to usage of regular recursion; tail recursion might help here.